# Replacing Native Attributes with New Invocation Handler

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am wanting to replace native override methods with a new invocation handler received from a previous question. It is crashing at setOnClickListener as I do not know what jobject needs to be returned inside createProxyInstance method body. As requested, a new question was made for this request. Please refer to previous question 2 years ago. Returning proxy instance jobject receives bad argument error with setOnClickListener. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/124247982?noredirect=1

**Java**

```
class MyInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private long cfunc;
    MyInvocationHandler(long cfunc) { this.cfunc = cfunc; }
    @Override
    public native Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args);
}

class Activity extends Service {
    Object getProxy (MyInvocationHandler mih) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = new ClassLoader() {
            @Override
            public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                return super.loadClass(name);
            }
        };
        return java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(classLoader, new Class[] { }, mih);
    }
}
```

**C++**

```
typedef jobject (*CFunc)(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject proxy, jobject method, jobjectArray args);
extern "C" jobject Java_com_app_core_MyInvocationHandler_invoke(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject proxy, jobject method, jobjectArray args) {
    jclass cls_myIH = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jfieldID fld_myIH_cfunc = env->GetFieldID(cls_myIH, "cfunc", "J");
    CFunc cfunc = (CFunc)env->GetLongField(obj, fld_myIH_cfunc);
    cfunc(env, obj, proxy, method, args);
    return nullptr;
}

jobject createProxyInstance(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, CFunc cfunc) {
    jclass cls_IH = env->FindClass("com/app/core/MyInvocationHandler");
    jmethodID cst_IH = env->GetMethodID(cls_IH, "<init>", "(J)V");
    jobject myIH = env->NewObject(cls_IH, cst_IH, (jlong)cfunc);

    jclass klass2 = env->FindClass("com/app/core/Activity");
    jmethodID method2 = env->GetMethodID(klass2, "getProxy", "(Lcom/app/core/MyInvocationHandler;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    env->CallObjectMethod(continuedContext, method2, myIH);
}

jobject aa (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject proxy, jobject method, jobjectArray args) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TEST", "SUCCESS");
}

void setListeners() {
    klass = env->FindClass("android/view/View");
    method = env->GetMethodID(klass, "setOnClickListener", "(Landroid/view/View$OnClickListener;)V");
    klass = env->FindClass("android/view/View$OnClickListener");
    env->CallVoidMethod(imageView, method, createProxyInstance(env, klass, &aa));
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you create a new classloader as opposed to grabbing the one associated with your `Activity`? (`Activity.class.getClassLoader()`)

Comment: More so to learn about it. Another I knew it wouldn't harm anything.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `createProxyInstance` must obviously be that of the call to `getProxy`, but you are missing something important: the `setOnClickListener` expects an object that implements the `android/view/View$OnClickListener` interface.

You already pass this class to `createProxyInstance`, so you just need to get it to `getProxy`.

Change `getProxy` to the following:

```
Object getProxy (MyInvocationHandler mih, Class<?> target) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    return java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(classLoader, new Class[] { target }, mih);
}
```

and adapt `createProxyInstance` as follows:

```
jobject createProxyInstance(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, CFunc cfunc) {
    jclass cls_IH = env->FindClass("com/app/core/MyInvocationHandler");
    jmethodID cst_IH = env->GetMethodID(cls_IH, "<init>", "(J)V");
    jobject myIH = env->NewObject(cls_IH, cst_IH, (jlong)cfunc);

    jclass klass2 = env->FindClass("com/app/core/Activity");
    jmethodID method2 = env->GetMethodID(klass2, "getProxy", "(Lcom/app/core/MyInvocationHandler;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    return env->CallObjectMethod(continuedContext, method2, myIH, cls);
}
```

Comment: My log shows, but it crashes after in invoke method. Not really showing how it is exactly.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I added a log inside the CFunc type method I made. It showed when I clicked on my image, but it later crashed. This showed in log ```CheckJNI::DeleteRef```. Invoke method was last in the error stack.

Comment: Do you really expect anyone to be able to debug your problem from a one sentence description of the error?

Comment: Well when I'm given code, I'd expect it to be tested instead of me doing all of the testing. Your previous answer in the other question was not filled out to its fullest leaving me to pick the dots. Im new to this type of work and would appreciate a wells done work/assistance.

Comment: Later checking, your invoke method body is what's crashing the app after I click my image. This can be tested by returning nullptr at the start of the method. The log I have in my image listener does display before it crashes. Somewhere in your code, it is crashing.

Comment: This answer is worth exactly what you paid for it. I wish you the best of luck in figuring out the problem yourself. As for testing: your question is a lump of disconnected code snippets and far from a [mre]. If you don't do your homework, don't expect well-tested code from internet strangers who are just trying to help.